# Is it possible to set role icons with discord.js v13?

Tags: discord.js

Is it possible to set the role icon through discord.js? I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation, so i decided to ask just in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<Role>.setIcon(icon);
```

Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setIcon

Comment: That is strange, I've been looking there and didn't find it, probably past by me and didn't realise. thanks a ton :)